# Find match values in R by two conditions, one being a date within a time range

Tags: r, date, if-statement, merge, nested-loops

I have two different data frames ("Birth", "Test"). they both have a column of ID numbers ("mid.b", "mid.t") with some of the ID's appearing in both data frames (even several times), and no other data in common. They both also have a column with a date value. In each data frame, an ID can appear several times, but each combination of an ID-number and Date is unique.

**I would like to get a value from the "res.num" column in the "Test" data frame, with its matched m.event value from "birth" DF**- if the ID in the "mid.t" matches an id in "mid.b", and if the date in "Test" is no more than 7 months prior to the date in "Birth", of that ID.

by now i have function that calculate the month gap:

example to the data frames:

```
mid.t<-c(628941,628979,64976)
res.num<-c("A59646","A60921","A61903")
date.t<-c("2016.12.11","2017.10.16","2018.06.13")
test<-cbind.data.frame(mid.t,res.num,date.t)

mid.b<-c(628941,628979,64976)
m.event<-c(21219464,22457757,23365285)
date.b<-c("2017.01.26","2018.02.12","2020.11.13")
birth<-cbind.data.frame(mid.b,m.event,date.b)
```

by now, i have the function that calculate the date gap in month:

```
mon_ymd<-function(x,y){
gap<-(as.yearmon(strptime(x, format = "%Y.%m.%d"))-as.yearmon(strptime(y, format="%Y.%m.%d")))*12
  return(gap)}
```

and a very nice code that doesn't work completely:
i get: Error in if (idb == idt) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

```
for (idt in test$mid.t){
  for (idb in birth$mid.b){
    x<-birth[birth$mid.b==idb,]$date.b
    y<-test[test$mid.t==idt,]$date.t
    if (idb==idt){
    gapmon<-mon_ymd(x,y)
      if ((gapmon<=7)&(gapmon>=0)){
        print(test[test$mid.t==idt,]$res.num)
}}}}
```

Comment: Is there any particular part of this where you are stuck? This question, as-is, is much too broad to be answered here effectively. Ultimately this feels like the sort of thing that would be a lot easier to pull of in a database.

Comment: is it merge 2 files or 2 tables?

Comment: 2 files, but i can make it 2 tables (only one sheet)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure this is what you need, but this is what I could managed to translate from your question: *Match the two dataframes and then get the row where the month gap between the two is 7 or greater*

```
library("dplyr")
library("zoo")

filter(
     left_join(birth, test, by = c("mid.b" = "mid.t")) %>% 
     mutate(date.t = as.yearmon(strptime(date.t, format = "%Y.%m.%d")),
            date.b = as.yearmon(strptime(date.b, format = "%Y.%m.%d")), 
            gap = ifelse((date.t - date.b) * 12 <= -7, TRUE, FALSE)
       ), gap == TRUE)


#   mid.b  m.event    date.b res.num    date.t   gap
#1  64976 23365285 nov. 2020  A61903 jun. 2018  TRUE
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. if I run this I get "0 rows", when I clearly need to get something (according to the data base). Anyway, I want the gap to be between 0 and 7, including.

Comment: Then just a matter of changing `date.b - date.t` for `date.t - date.b`. The change has been made in the answer.

Comment: sorry for the delay. i still got "0 rows" and it's running too fast, so i think there is another porblem in the code. i'll try to find it, but if you have an idea, i'll be happy to hear from you. thanks again.

Comment: I made the correction mentioned in the comment. It runs without problems with your example data.